# Elixir equivalent to while true

Tags: python, while-loop, elixir

I want  to rewrite this method (written here in Python) in Elixir

```python
def something()
    while True:
        x = function()
        y = function()
        if x != y:
            return x
```

`function()` generates a random value, so the execution would end sooner or later.

My problem is to translate the `while True` in the most "functional way" possible.

I came up with this solution, but I think is not very readable.

```ex
def something() do
    internal(function(), function())
end

defp internal(a, a) do
    internal(function(), function())
end

defp internal(a, _) do
    a
end
```

Is there a better way to do it?

PS: `function()` must be always called twice at every cycle and it cannot be rewritten.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elixir has variables and `if` expressions too, so all you really need to do is replace `while True` with a recursive call:

```
  def something() do
    x = function()
    y = function()

    if x != y do
      x
    else
      something()
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

Recursion is your friend

```elixir
  def something do
    x = function()
    y = function()
    if x != y, do: x, else: something()
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your solution is not bad, it's just a matter of getting used to seeing multiple function clauses in action. You could re-arrange it a bit to make it more readable, but that's just personal preference.

```elixir
def something(), do: something(nil, nil)
defp something(x, x), do: something(function(), function())
defp something(x, _y), do: x
```

The `(x, x)` clause will get executed when the arguments are equal.

The `(x, _y)` clause, which just returns `x`, gets executed otherwise.

But I have to admit potibas' answer is pretty simple and probably a good compromise. I think I prefer the function clause way **in general** because it makes the arguments explicit and hides away fewer side-effects.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of diversity, here is not recursive answer, based on [`Stream.iterate/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html?#iterate/2) and [`Stream.take_while/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html#take_while/2). Note, that any infinite stream generator might be used instead of `iterate/2`, e. g. [`Stream.cycle/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html#cycle/1).

```rb
0
|> Stream.iterate(&(&1 + 1))
|> Stream.map(fn _ -> {f1(), f2()} end)
|> Stream.take_while(fn {x, y} -> x != y end)
|> Enum.to_list()
```

In many cases, this solution is more reliable.